# Distribution of pointer keys in a Skip-list node

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, data-structures, probabilistic-algorithms

Suppose we have a list of $N$ keys where the distribution of keys follows $f(x)$.

We construct a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) over the keys.

Now if I pick a key (e.g. `31` in the following picture), what are the **Expected value of keys** that it points to?

For example, key `31` points to: `[38,44,55]`. Considering that I know `31` has `k` pointers (here k=3), **how can I compute the expected distribution of values it points to**?

P.S. I am also interested to compute the INDEX of values it points to (e.g. `31` is the `5th` key, and points to `6th`, `8th`, and `10th` keys). Can I infer these [expected] index numbers, too?

[image]